Issue when loading framer-motion page through Router
I will explain my problem in a scenario

I am using Framer motion with react for animation
After creating react using vite, I created a component folder under src folder
I created Motion.jsx file under components folder.
There are multiple pages in my Application, so I use useNavigate() to route to different pages
In App.jsx I used react-router-dom for routing

How it should work:

when I navigate from landing.jsx to Motion.jsx file, The Motion.jsx file should load the <motion.div> with the given varients, that is loading them in slight delay
When I again click reload again, The Motion.jsx file should reload the <motion.div> with the given varients, that is loading them in slight delay

How it is working:

when I navigate from landing.jsx to Motion.jsx file, The Motion.jsx file is loading the <motion.div> with the given varients, that is loading them in slight delay.
When I again click reload again, The Motion.jsx file is reloading the first two div without any delay and other div with the correct delay

I have given the files below:
Motion.jsx --->
import {
    motion,
} from "framer-motion"

const gridContainerVariants = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0 },
    show: {
        opacity: 1,
        transition: {
            staggerChildren: 0.25,
        },
    },
}

const gridSquareVariants = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0 },
    show: { opacity: 1 },
}

const Motion = () => {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-10 overflow-x-hidden">
            <motion.div
                variants={gridContainerVariants}
                initial="hidden"
                animate="show"
                className="grid grid-cols-3 p-10 gap-10"
            >
                {/* Fade Up */}
                <motion.div
                    variants={gridSquareVariants}
                    className="bg-slate-800 aspect-square rounded-lg justify-center flex items-center gap-10"
                >
                </motion.div>
                {/* Shape Shifting */}
                <motion.div
                    variants={gridSquareVariants}
                    className="bg-slate-800 aspect-square rounded-lg justify-center flex items-center gap-10"
                >
                </motion.div>
                {/* Button */}
                <motion.div
                    variants={gridSquareVariants}
                    className="bg-slate-800 aspect-square rounded-lg justify-center flex items-center gap-10"
                >
                </motion.div>
                {/* Drag */}
                <motion.div
                    variants={gridSquareVariants}
                    className="bg-slate-800 aspect-square rounded-lg justify-center flex items-center gap-10"
                >
                </motion.div>
                {/* Scroll Progress */}
                <motion.div
                    variants={gridSquareVariants}
                    className="bg-slate-800 aspect-square rounded-lg justify-center flex items-center gap-10"
                >
                </motion.div>
                {/* SVG Animation */}
                <motion.div
                    variants={gridSquareVariants}
                    className="bg-slate-800 aspect-square rounded-lg justify-center flex items-center gap-10"
                >
                </motion.div>
            </motion.div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Motion


App.jsx -->
import Motion from "./components/FramerMotion/Motion";
import Hello from "./components/HelloTest/Hello";
import Auction from "./components/HOC/Auction";
import MovingBorder from "./components/Tailwind/MovingBorder";
import ResponsiveNavigation1 from "./components/Tailwind/ResponsiveNavigation1";
import ResponsiveNavigation2 from "./components/Tailwind/ResponsiveNavigation2";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Hello />} />
                    <Route path="/auction" element={<Auction />} />
                    <Route path="/movingborder" element={<MovingBorder />} />
                    <Route path="/responsivenavigation1" element={<ResponsiveNavigation1 />}/>
                    <Route path="/responsivenavigation2" element={<ResponsiveNavigation2 />}/>
                    <Route path="/motion" element={<Motion />} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;


fileTree -->
/public/
  └─ vite.svg
/src/
  /components/
    /FramerMotion/
      └─ Motion.jsx
    /HelloTest/
      └─ Hello.jsx
    /HOC/
      ├─ Auction.jsx
      ├─ HOC.jsx
      ├─ Person1.jsx
      └─ Person2.jsx
    /Tailwind/
      ├─ MovingBorder.jsx
      ├─ ResponsiveNavigation1.jsx
      └─ ResponsiveNavigation2.jsx
  ├─ App.jsx
  ├─ index.css
  └─ main.jsx
/.gitignore
/eslint.config.js
/index.html
/package.json
/postcss.config.js
/README.md
/tailwind.config.js
/vite.config.js


Can you [edit] to share a complete [mcve] that includes any React-Router-DOM code? I invite you to also take the full [tour] and to review Help/How to Ask to learn additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

You can try to use the 'useLocation' hook from 'react-router-dom' to create a unique key for your 'motion.div', ensuring it re-mounts on navigation and refresh.Here is example code for this:
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Motion = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const gridContainerVariants = {
        hidden: { opacity: 0 },
        show: {
            opacity: 1,
            transition: { staggerChildren: 0.25 },
        },
    };

    const gridSquareVariants = {
        hidden: { opacity: 0 },
        show: { opacity: 1 },
    };

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-10 overflow-x-hidden">
            <motion.div
                key={location.key} // Unique key for re-mounting
                variants={gridContainerVariants}
                initial="hidden"
                animate="show"
                className="grid grid-cols-3 p-10 gap-10"
            >
                {Array.from({ length: 6 }).map((_, index) => (
                    <motion.div
                        key={index}
                        variants={gridSquareVariants}
                        className="bg-slate-800 aspect-square rounded-lg"
                    />
                ))}
            </motion.div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Motion;


Thanks the answer But the issue is still pertaining.
Please refer to the attached video link
https://jmp.sh/qJVLOYei
This video has a visual representation of the bug
